# Solution to identify "Similar Product Images"?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud, google-compute-engine, amazon-rekognition

I want to build a cloud based solution in which I would give a pool of images; and then ask for "find similar image to a particular image from this pool of images"  !! Pool of images can be like "all t-shirt" images. Hence, similar images mean "t-shirt with similar design/color/sleeves" etc.

Tagging solution won't work as they are at very high level.

AWS Rekognition gives "facial similarities" .. but not "product similarities" .. it does not work like for images of dresses..

I am open to use any cloud providers; but all are providing "tags" of the image which won't help me.

One solution could be that I use some ML framework like MXNet/Tensorflow, create my own models, train them and then use.. But is there any other ready made solution on any of cloud providers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ibm-bluemix has an api to find similar images https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/#find_similar

Answer (score 1):

Using the Azure Cognitive Services ([Computer Vision](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) to be more precise) you can get categories, tags, a caption and even more info for images. Processing all your images would provide tags for your image pool. And that enables you to get similar images based on (multiple) identical tags.

> This feature returns information about visual content found in an image. Use tagging, descriptions, and domain-specific models to identify content and label it with confidence. Apply the adult/racy settings to enable automated restriction of adult content. Identify image types and color schemes in pictures.

An example of (part of) a result of the Computer Vision API:

[image: Computer Vision example]

```
Description{
    "Tags": [
        "train",
        "platform",
        "station",
        "building",
        "indoor",
        "subway",
        "track",
        "walking",
        "waiting",
        "pulling",
        "board",
        "people",
        "man",
        "luggage",
        "standing",
        "holding",
        "large",
        "woman",
        "yellow",
        "suitcase"
    ],
    "Captions": [
        {
            "Text": "people waiting at a train station",
            "Confidence": 0.8331026
        }
    ]
}
Tags[
    {
        "Name": "train",
        "Confidence": 0.9975446
    },
    {
        "Name": "platform",
        "Confidence": 0.995543063
    },
    {
        "Name": "station",
        "Confidence": 0.9798007
    },
    {
        "Name": "indoor",
        "Confidence": 0.927719653
    },
    {
        "Name": "subway",
        "Confidence": 0.838939846
    },
    {
        "Name": "pulling",
        "Confidence": 0.431715637
    }
]
```

Comment: this won't work.. because I will be uploading suppose pool of t-shirts.. now I need to know similar looking t-shirts

Comment: You could (should) have been more specific with your question. This solution enables you to find similar images from a set of available images, just like you asked. Only now you're stating that you want to find similar t-shirts... And I still think you can process the images in the pool and try to find similar images based on the tags Computer Vision will find for you. Why are you so sure it won't work? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Bing Image Search API (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-image-search-api/) which allows you to do an image search based on specified criteria within your solution...

Comment: this won't work.. because I will be uploading suppose image pool of t-shirts.. now I need to know similar looking t-shirts.. Just tags wont help

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of things here. Use an image tagging service [aws rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/), or any of those listed above) then create some training data with like images, and upload that into something like [aws machine learning](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/). This is a bit similar to what has been brought up earlier, however I am trying to elucidate that while tagging might not be the end all be all of your solution, it will likely play a role as a first to step to a more complex process.

Answer (score 0):

pls check the site http://cloudsight.ai/api, and try the demo. the sample result would be

```
    {
        "token": "BBKA0lW9O-B2eamXUysdXA",
        "url": "http://assets.cloudsight.ai/uploads/image_request/image/314/314978/314978186/79379_86cb4e2611d6b0a3287a926a1ca1fe51_image1_zoom.jpg",
        "ttl": 54,
        "status": "completed",
        "name": "men's red and black checkered button-up shirt"
    }

{
    "token": "bjX7nWGs0toajIDwyvXxlw",
    "url": "http://assets.cloudsight.ai/uploads/image_request/image/314/314987/314987168/11.jpg",
    "ttl": 54,
    "status": "completed",
    "name": "blue, gray and navy blue stripe crew-neck T-shirt"
}
```